# How to remove the outer border of a table within another table (HTML)

Tags: html, css, html-table

In my borderless `HTML table` I replaced the `heading` of a `column` with a compound heading, consisting of three parts (see image). I did this by inserting a second table into the corresponding `heading element`. However, **I am at a loss to remove the outer border of that table**. In the image, the blue background color of the `heading element` remains visible. The table should be flush with the `heading element`, so that the blue of the `heading element` no longer is visible. How can this be achieved?

[image]

Here is the `HTML code` of the table in the image:

```css
table {
  color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

th {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  background-color: olive;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:green">A</th>
    <th style="background-color:blue">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th style="background-color:maroon" colspan="2">B</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="background-color:red">x</th>
          <th style="background-color:orange">y</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:purple">C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>550</td>
    <td>670</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS rule to remove the padding from that cell:

```
body > table > tbody > tr:first-child > th:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
body > table > tbody > tr:first-child > th:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table {
 color: white;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: none;
}
th {
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}
td {
 background-color: olive;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}   
</style>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:green">A</th>
    <th style="background-color:blue">
      <table>
    <tr><th style="background-color:maroon" colspan="2">B</th></tr>
    <tr>
          <th style="background-color:red">x</th>
          <th style="background-color:orange">y</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:purple">C</th>  
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>550</td>
    <td>670</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>

html
css
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class to remove the padding.

```css
table {
  color: white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none;
}

th {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.no-padding { padding: 0 }

td {
  background-color: olive;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:green">A</th>
    <th class="no-padding" style="background-color:blue">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th style="background-color:maroon" colspan="2">B</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="background-color:red">x</th>
          <th style="background-color:orange">y</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
    <th style="background-color:purple">C</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>400</td>
    <td>500</td>
    <td>600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>550</td>
    <td>670</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```